# create textbox inside select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my simple html code for drop down list:-

```
<span id="Div_List">
    <label for="Gender">For:</label>
    <select name="Gender" id="Sex">
      <option value="1">1000mtr</option>
      <option value="2">1500mtr</option>
      <option value="3">2000mtr</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

i want to create one textbox inside `select`.
how its possible?
if any way to do this please suggest your idea.
thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to have any element inside a `<select>` other than `<option>` - and `<option>` cannot have elements inside it either.

Comment: Search the web for *html combobox*

Comment: You cannot have a textbox within a select-element, it wouldn't be valid HTML. You would have to create a custom dropdown based on other elements, like `<div>` elements. Then you could add whatever elements you want within it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like **[this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)**.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible using strict html. You have to emulate it.

For example [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is really nice plugin which you can check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.comboBox()` in jQuery.It will hide the selectbox and it creates a text box to enter the data which is going to autopopulate

Comment: @Jack Php check my answer once

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) for more info:

I hope it helps.